# How should I run front end integration tests in spring boot?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a simple spring boot project that has a maven structure like this:

```
project
  - backend (spring boot)
  - frontend (angular)
```

I got the project configured so *IT.java classes run during integration test phase of maven and they are successfully testing the Spring Boot REST API with an H2 database.

I'm trying to configure the project so my cucumber tests that interact with the browser will run during the integration test phase of the project. The cucumber tests start up ok but fail for the simple reason the angular files don't get served by the spring boot application when it starts.

In backend/src/main/resources/static I have a simple index.html file. When the cucumber tests run they open a browser an I see the content of that file.

In the backend module (war) pom I copy the dist content from the angular build...

```
    <build>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>some.package.Boot</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.war.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>${root.context}</warName>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <resources>
          <resource>
           <directory>../frontend/<appname>/dist/frontend</directory>
            <!--<targetPath>src/main/resources/static</targetPath>-->
            <targetPath>static</targetPath>
           </resource>
         </resources>
   </build>
```

In the resultant war file the angular files are packaged up into WEB-INF/classes/static/.

You'll note from above I also tried getting the angular code copied into resources/static, but that puts the files in target/classes/src/main/resources/static, so that isn't the right approach!

Yet the cucumber tests still only see the content of the index.html file from src/main/resources/static when they run.

Potentially we could move the angular app into the same src tree as the java/webapp code, but that's not an option.

How can I persuade Spring Boot to use the war in target rather what it *appears* to be doing and service content from source?

Versions:
Java 11

Maven war plugin 3.2.2

Springboot version defined in parent pom as 2.1.3.RELEASE

- spring-boot-starter-web
- spring-boot-starter-data-rest
- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
- spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc
- spring-boot-starter-tomcat (not sure I need this one)